# Cl editor not working in default-modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, popup, cleditor

Why Cl Editor can not Working In Popup. may be its work sometime

[image: Here Cl editor Image]

This is the code i can run in popup using ajax: 
Its May be Some time working or some time can not work:
List.php can display list of job. on tr td tag.

List.php

```
<div id="default-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
<td  width="5%" class="text-center"><a onclick="show_popup(<?php echo $id; ?>)" rel="<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-icon"><i class="icon-file6"></i></a></td>

<script type="text/javascript">

function show_popup(id)
{
   $('#default-modal').modal('show');
   $.ajax({
      url: 'job_popup.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {id:id},
      cache: false,
      success: function(response)
       {
        $('#default-modal').html(response);
       }
 });

}
```

job_popup.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css" />
<script src="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js"></script>
<script src="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#desc").cleditor();
          });
    $('.form-control').each(function(){
this.contentEditable = true;
  });
</script>



 <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control"><?php echo $desc?> </textarea>
```

Comment: Cannot see `<input id="input">`

Comment: i replace with desc. but i can't solve

Comment: Why are you initialising `cleditor` twice? Remove the first call and try again. Also, when you use jQuery `.each` you should use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Comment: wait... i try  it

Comment: no working bro. please give me another solution

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding editor's jQuery code (which is in document.ready function) in on click event of popup.

Comment: Add your code here with popup so i can help you more.

Comment: hello you can see now

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: 'job_popup.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {id:id},
      cache: false,
      success: function(response)
       {
        $('#default-modal').html(response);
$("#desc").cleditor();
      $("#desc").cleditor({
        fonts: // font names in the font popup
                "Arial,Arial Black,Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Narrow,Garamond," +
                "Georgia,Impact,Sans Serif,Serif,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana"+
                "400 20px/30px 'Roboto', sans-serif"
      });}
 });

Comment: Replace your ajax with above in show_popup function and check.

Comment: and remove   $("#desc").cleditor(); from popup page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133440/discussion-between-meena-patel-and-darshana-rana).